# How to put additional files into auto-py-to-exe --onefile mode?

Tags: python, png, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Im using `auto-py-to-exe` with `img = tkinter.Image("photo", file = "./square.png")`. (i did `import tkinter`) It works by running it through the .py file but after i convert it in `--onefile` mode using `auto-py-to-exe` it just says that the file is non-existant. Strangely if I copy/paste a `square.png` beside the `.exe` file it works using that image.

Here's the full code.

```
import turtle
import tkinter
import time
import random

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.title("Pixel")
img = tkinter.Image("photo", file = "./square.png")
turtle._Screen._root.iconphoto(True, img)

#[turtle drawing stuff below.]
```